# AWS t2 instance CPUCreditBalance and baseline performance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I am trying to understand `CPUCreditBalance` for AWS `t2`instances. Based on AWS documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-instances.html#t2-instances-cpu-credits), a `t2.micro` with zero `CPUCreditBalance` should be capped to 10% of CPU usage, however same usage is being shown as 20% on the instance.

See below my instance usage info. As per AWS CloudWatch

[image: cloudwatch-stats]

usage seem to be limited to around 10%. However `top`, `sar` utilities on instance show as `20%` (around 80% being stolen by hypervisor)

[image: sar]

What am i missing?

**UPDATE:**

Above test was done on an `Amazon AMI` running `4.4.41-36.55.amzn1.x86_64` kernel, however I tried similar test on `Redhat 7.3 AMI` running `3.10.0-514.el7.x86_64` kernel and that looked fine.

See results below with RedHat 7.3

[image: RedHat AMI CloudWatch]

`sar` usage was showing ~ 10% as cloudwatch

[image]

PS: I used `Maximum` values for Cloudwatch metrics here instead of default `Average`

Comment: I wonder if it is being confused by Hyperthreading?

Comment: It's not exactly an instantaneous peak cap... it's a rolling average cap.  Drop your utilization to 5% for one minute and you can have ~15% the next.  Drop to 5% for 2 minutes, and you can have ~20% for the next 1.  The balances are actually calulated with millisecond resolution but only reported to CloudWatch every 5 minutes (or possibly every 1 minute, with enhanced monitoring enabled).  Could that explain what you see?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - I also thought about that, but the behavior seen to be dependent on the kernel. See my update